# select element with multiple checkboxes

Tags: html, css, checkbox

[image]

Gmail has the feature where you can select labels using checkboxes and it is hidden inside a div element where you can scroll up and down.

It also allows you to have customized actions like create new label at the bottom.

It also allows you to do filtering at the top with a simple search bar.

What is the simplest way to implement something like that and allow me to put in customized actions like the Create new label at the bottom?

At the barest minimum have a way to display all the checkboxes in a scrollable div or select element.

UPDATE:

Currently, I have only the following checkboxes

```
<div class="input select">
    <label for="SiteSite">Sites</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="data[Site][Site]" value="" id="SiteSite">

<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Site][Site][]" value="1" id="SiteSite1"><label for="SiteSite1">ODSite:P11379-440YishunAve11 HWSW_ESTA ENO21.000070.10001 92640145</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Site][Site][]" value="2" id="SiteSite2"><label for="SiteSite2">ODSite:P11374-SGRecClub HWSW_ESTA ENO21.000070.10002 92640147</label></div>

</div>
```

Comment: You need to show some effort. What have you tried?

Comment: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin called [**Select2**](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/), which has all the options you expect from a `<SELECT>` tag.

http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/543/select2.png